# Permanently close a port in Bash

Tags: centos, process, kill, port-forwarding, port

I am trying to kill a process (in CentOS) that is listening to a port that was set up with port forwarding. I have tried all the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346211/how-to-kill-a-process-on-a-port-on-ubuntu but a new process, with a new pid seems to be "resurrecting" the listening to the port. Every time I kill on pid, a new one takes its place. I also tried: `sudo ufw deny $port_number` but got an error as well.

How can I permanently close port?

Comment: What version of CentOS are you running? There is no `ufw` in CentOS.

Comment: Which process is that? Resurrection is something that just happens, you might have to tell the process not to reopen the port.

Comment: The solution here will revolve around determining how a new process is restarted. It might be a parent that you haven't found. It out might be `systemd`. Etc. And then you don't need to worry about closing the port because it won't be open

Answer (score 1):

ufw closes the port in the firewall, meaning no external host can access that port. But that doesn't prevent a program from listening on that port. If not explicitly denied in the firewall a program on the local host could still access that port, but nobody over the network can.

Do you understand the difference?

BTW, you can find the program with `lsof -i :1234`

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, the answer was following what @roaima said, finding the process that was itself restarting the process. Fixing this solved the problem.